# when i try to parse the code into csv file it gives me this:

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-science

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>

```
with open('F:\Temp\python\matches-details.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(matches_details)
        print("file created")
```

I edited the code to be:

```
with open('F:\Temp\python\matches-details.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8) as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(matches_details)``
    print("file created")
```

but the text in my csv file become as this:
(Ø§Ù„ÙØ±ÙŠÙ‚ Ø§Ù„Ø£ÙˆÙ„)

Comment: Hello welcome to Stackoverflow. Checkout the [tour] and [ask]. You're going to have a little more context in your question. With what you currently have given, it difficult to infer what your issues is.

Comment: Not related to the error, but remember to use a raw string when it contains literal backslash characters.

Comment: You could try opening it with an encoding, like: `with open('F:\Temp\python\matches-details.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `encoding='utf-8'` when opening it:

```py
with open('F:\Temp\python\matches-details.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(matches_details)
    print("file created")
```

Comment: the text im my csv file is like that:( Ù†ÙˆØ¹ Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø·ÙˆÙ„Ø©)